# Rails 4 - How to insert an additional row when you submit a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a simple application with Ruby on Rails. I have three tables in my database: **users**, **events** and **invites**.

Any user can create an invite via form, where he/she selects the **user**, that he/she wants to invite, and the **event**, that he/she wants to invite that person to.

Now, I would like to make it so that everytime somebody creates an invite, he/she also invites another user called **"Intruder"**.

So, everytime the invite form is submitted, two rows should be inserted into the database:

- First with the data that the user picked
- Second where user_id matches the id of the "Intruder", while event_id is the same as in the first row.

Here's my invites controller:

```
  def new
    @invite = Invite.new
    @users = User.where.not(:id => current_user).order(full_name: :ASC)
    @user = User.new
    @events = Event.where(:user_id => current_user).order(startsAt: :ASC)
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @users = User.where.not(:id => current_user).order(full_name: :ASC)
    @user = User.new
    @events = Event.where(:user_id => current_user).order(startsAt: :ASC)
    @event = Event.new
    @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invite.save
        format.html { redirect_to events_path, notice: 'Invite was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invite }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @invite.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def invite_params
    params.require(:invite).permit(:attending, :user_id, :event_id)
  end
```

Here's my form for creating a new invite:

```
<%= form_for(@invite) do |f| %>
  <% if @invite.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@invite.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this invite from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @invite.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id, 'Name' %>
    <%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(@users.collect { | user | [user.full_name, user.id] }, @user.id), {}, class: 'inv-select' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :event_id %>
    <%= f.select :event_id, options_for_select(@events.collect { | event | [event.title, event.id] }, @event.id), {}, class: 'inv-select' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Invite' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to add the *Intruder* part to your views since it's just a backend implementation detail if I understood your question correctly.

So, you can extract the *Intruder* insertion part to a method and call it right after inserting the new invitation for the other user:

```
def create
  @users = User.where.not(:id => current_user).order(full_name: :ASC)
  @user = User.new
  @events = Event.where(:user_id => current_user).order(startsAt: :ASC)
  @event = Event.new
  @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @invite.save && invite_intruder          
      format.html { redirect_to events_path, notice: 'Invite was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invite }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @invite.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

protected

def invite_intruder
  intruder = User.find_by(full_name: "Intruder")
  Invite.new(event_id: invite_params[:event_id], user_id: intruder.id).save
end
```

You'll probably want to add some custom error handling in case the invitation to *Intruder* fails, but it's not clear if you want this second invitation to be transparent to the user or hidden.

Comment: You understood me correctly. I want the second invitation to be transparent to the user, but I know how to handle that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an auxiliary attribute to the invite model, to hold the intruder:

```
attr_accesor :intruder_id
```

You can add the intruder in the form:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :intruder_id, 'Intruder' %>
  <%= f.select :intruder_id, options_for_select(@users.collect { | user | [user.full_name, user.id] }), {}, class: 'inv-select' %>
</div>
```

Add the intruder_id to params

```
def invite_params
  params.require(:invite).permit(:attending, :user_id, :intruder_id, :event_id)
end
```

You don't need user and event in the new

```
def new
  @invite = Invite.new
  @users = User.where.not(:id => current_user).order(full_name: :ASC)
  @events = Event.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order(startsAt: :ASC)
end
```

Create two invites:

```
def create
  @users = User.where.not(:id => current_user).order(full_name: :ASC)
  @events = Event.where(:user_id => current_user).order(startsAt: :ASC)
  @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
  @intruder_invite Invite.new(invite_params)
  @intruder_invite.user_id = invite_params[:intruder_id] # Change the invitee

  respond_to do |format|
    if @invite.save
      if @intruder_invite.save
        format.html { redirect_to events_path, notice: 'Main and intruder invites were successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invite }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to events_path, notice: 'Main invite was created, but an error prevented the intruder invite to be created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invite }
      end
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @invite.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the function of the [callbacks mechanism](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) in rails, probably the before_create callback as it won't require an additional save.

```
class Invite < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :add_intruder

  protected

  def add_intruder
    self.users << User.find_by full_name: "Intruder"
  end

end
```

Although TBH a better way would be to handle this in SQL via a trigger.